# Apache Pig: Appending current date and time as a constant value to each record generated

Tags: datetime, hadoop, foreach, append, apache-pig

Suppose I have a table (input) where every record has:

```
id:chararray
name: chararray
```

My required output is a relation with the schema:

```
datetoday:any Data type
id:chararray
name:chararray
```

I basically want to make sure that the time at which the script was run is recorded as datetoday against every record that I am generating.

How can I achieve this? Especially using `FOREACH…GENERATE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this 
  A = <Load your input data>
  B = FOREACH A GENERATE CurrentTime() AS datetoday,id,name;

Output will be generated in datetime format something like this
    (2014-10-11T05:32:04.188+05:30,10,name1)
    (2014-10-11T05:32:04.188+05:30,20,name2)
```